# How can I know if my Android app is in the foreground including when showing an interstitial ad?

Tags: android

After reading all the answers for questions like "how can I know if my Android app is in the background/foreground" I am still unsure what to do while an interstitial is running?

The [preferred answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5862048/704836) is basically to track it yourself by manually tracking `onPause` and `onResume` or using the new `lifecycle` library from Google. This works well, however this assumes you control the code for all the activities, when an interstitial runs that isn't your own `Activity` so this method won't work for it.

Other answers involve calling `ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()` or `ActivityManager.getRunningTasks()`. These are of course not recommend and shouldn't be used. I'm also guessing future policy changes might limit this.

So how can I know if my app is on the foreground even while showing an interstitial ad?

Since someone might ask why I need to know this. My app uses the `WebView`. The `WebView` has a nasty habit of letting `Javascript` continue to run even when `onPause()` is called on the `WebView`. The only way I have found of stopping it is to run `webView.pauseTimers()` but that method applies to all WebViews, not just the one you called it on. So if I call that on when my `onPause()` is called on my `Activity` right before an interstitial ad, then the interstitial ad will probably freeze and might even ANR.

Answer (score -1):

If you have Application class ,you can use that class to track.

```
public class StarterApplication extends Application implements LifecycleObserver {
 @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
  public void onAppBackgrounded() {
    //App in background ,do your background stuff
    Log.d( "onAppBackgrounded: ","called");

}

 @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
  public void onAppForegrounded() {
    // App in foreground,do your foreground stuff
    Log.d("onAppForegrounded: ","called");

}
```

Comment: Don't you have to add the `LifecycleObserver` to each `Activity` by calling `getLifecycle().addObserver()`? That won't work for `interstitials` because I don't control the code of their activities.